# HTTPContext.Current.User.Identity.Name not working inside a control?

Tags: asp.net, httpcontext, windows-identity

I have a label and I want to set text of this label to

```
HTTPContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

So I wrote

```
Text = '<%=HTTPContext.Current.User.Identity.Name %>'
```

but it doesn't work, however when I wrote this outside of the lable for example:

```
<h2>
<%=HTTPContext.Current.User.Identity.Name %>
</h2>
```

it works.

Comment: what is the text in `Text = '<%=HTTPContext.Current.User.Identity.Name %>'`

Comment: it is a asp:label control attribute

Comment: @HOY :why don't you write the label text in code behind??

Comment: change your text to something like 
<%# HTTPContext.Current.User.Identity.Name %>

Comment: @huMptyduMpty, I will use the Identity name as parameter, my point is not actually setting the text, but making it work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<asp:Label ID="lbUserName" 
           runat="server"
           Text='<%# HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name %>'
            />
```

in Page_Load

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack )
{
   lbUserName.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Still displays null (Edit: my mistake)

Comment: @HOY you should check your HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name is not null. the above solution should work

Comment: But what about the same issue in the problem? The databinding is not working in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9863899/passing-windows-user-id-as-parameter-to-sqldatasource-gives-databinding-exceptio

Answer (score 1):

use label like this

```
<asp:label id="lblx" runat="server" ><%= HTTPContext.Current.User.Identity.Name %></asp:label>
```

Answer (score 1):

To bind the text like this you will have to create your own custom expression builder.

First, add such class to your namespace:

```
using System.Web.Compilation;
using System.CodeDom;

[ExpressionPrefix("Code")]
public class CodeExpressionBuilder : ExpressionBuilder
{
    public override CodeExpression GetCodeExpression(BoundPropertyEntry entry,
        object parsedData, ExpressionBuilderContext context)
    {
        return new CodeSnippetExpression(entry.Expression);
    }
}
```

Next step is adding this to your web.config file:

```
<compilation debug="true">
    <expressionBuilders>
        <add expressionPrefix="Code" type="YourNameSpace.CodeExpressionBuilder"/>
    </expressionBuilders>
</compilation>
```

Then finally this should work:

```html
<asp:Label id="YourLabel" runat="server" Text='<%$ Code:HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name %>' />
```

Complicated way to achieve something simple, but this will allow you to use the syntax you want throught your whole project so might worth the extra effort.

[Reference](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/09/The-CodeExpressionBuilder.aspx).